# Understanding these weird types in 13F-HR table

Tags: stocks

I'm reading the 13F-HR table of BAC, https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/70858/000007085823000144/xslForm13F_X02/Q12023XmlTemplate.xml

Does anyone know the meaning of these?

1. The type of `ALKALINE WTR CO INC` is `COM NEW`, and there's no stock symbol associated with it.
2. The type of `AIR TRANS SVCS GROUP INC` is `NOTE 1.125%10/1`, don't understand it.
3. What about `*W EXP 11/05/202`?
4. `RIGHT 04/04/2023`

Comment: I'd ask BAC. Those look like data entry errors or "placeholder" values to me, but I honestly don't know.

Comment: @keshlam Tried, no one responded